# Can't boot ubuntu directly. Should I reinstall it?

Tags: boot, grub2, boot-repair, mate

I've migrated from Windows after 15 years of unsatisfaction. Installed Ubuntu MATE 15.10 on an old notebook that used to run Windows 7. The instalation went ok and I've been using the computer for a week with great satisfaction. But everytime I start my computer it goes to a black screen, like when your HD is completely empty. I have to boot it from the BIOS menu pressing f2 when it starts and then go into the GRUB menu also.

Tried to use Boot-Repair to fix it, but made it worse, since now it takes 10 seconds more to boot it. Can I fix this or should I reinstall it completely? I'm avoiding reinstalling Ubuntu MATE because I took quite some time installing stuff I needed.

Here's the pastebin that boot-repair gave me:
http://paste2.org/24vCtYVV